# Apply different sorting criteria as per table configuration

Tags: mysql

I have one mysql table "Routing" which contain 4 fields: Id, Rcost, Rpriority, Rmargin. We need to design a routing engine which will fetch the route as per below criteria:
1. Least Cost
2. Highest priority
3. Highest profitMargin

There different routing mechanisms will be listed with their priority in one diff table as per below rule .. 1=> Highest priority; 3=> Lowest priority; 0=> Not applicable.

if a given algorithm returns more than one route these chosen routes will be applied to the next algorithm, if multiple routes are again returned then these returned routes are again applied to the next algorithm until a single route is returned or no algorithms are left. If no algorithm is left then the first returned route in the list will be used.

Below is table content:

```
CREATE TABLE Routing (
        Id INT(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        Prefix VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        Route INT(10) NOT NULL,
        Cost FLOAT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        Priority INT(10) NULL DEFAULT 0,
        ProfitMargin INT(10),
        Quality INT(10),
        PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

Table data :

```
INSERT INTO Routing (Cost, Priority, ProfitMargin, Quality) VALUES (10, 20, 8, 4);
INSERT INTO Routing (Cost, Priority, ProfitMargin, Quality) VALUES (10, 20, 8, 4);
INSERT INTO Routing (Cost, Priority, ProfitMargin, Quality) VALUES (5, 18, 10, 4);
INSERT INTO Routing (Cost, Priority, ProfitMargin, Quality) VALUES (5, 18, 8, 4);
INSERT INTO Routing (Cost, Priority, ProfitMargin, Quality) VALUES (5, 19, 10, 4);
INSERT INTO Routing (Cost, Priority, ProfitMargin, Quality) VALUES (10, 20, 8, 4);
INSERT INTO Routing (Cost, Priority, ProfitMargin, Quality) VALUES (10, 20, 8, 4);
INSERT INTO Routing (Cost, ProfitMargin, Quality) VALUES (5, 10, 4);
```

The another table is carrying information about priority of application of sorting mechanism and their applicability as per rule described above.

Other table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RoutingCriteria;
CREATE TABLE RoutingCriteria (
                Id INT(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                Cost TINYINT,
                Priority TINYINT,
                Quality TINYINT,
                ProfitMargin    INT(4),
                PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

Table data:

```
insert into RoutingCriteria (Cost, Priority, Quality, ProfitMargin) VALUES(1, 2, 3, 4);
insert into RoutingCriteria (Cost, Priority, Quality, ProfitMargin) VALUES(4, 1, 3, 2);
insert into RoutingCriteria (Cost, Priority, Quality, ProfitMargin) VALUES(0, 2, 3, 0);
insert into RoutingCriteria (Cost, Priority, Quality, ProfitMargin) VALUES(1, 0, 3, 4);
```

We need to get route if we use different routeCriteria values.

Comment: So, what do you want to know exactly?

Comment: I am MySQL beginner and want to know how we can implement this. I need to get the single route id after applying mentioned routing mechanisms

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Routing ORDEY BY Cost ASC, Priority DESC, ProfitMargin DESC;`? The question is: what is the question?

Comment: Do you have the routes precalculated? I think you should first have an algorithm to select the route that applies the "filter" algorithms you mention and returns the result.

Comment: @Imre -- Routes are precalculated in the table ... we just need to find out the route Id after applying the sorting criteria. If we are mentioning priority for criteria as "0" then that will not be applicable and we need to sort as per rest of the criterias.

Answer (score 0):

Given the info this is i can come up with to suggest:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Routing 
 WHERE Priority > 0         -- excluding Not applicable
 ORDEY BY Cost ASC          -- Least Cost
        , Priority ASC      -- 1=> Highest; 3=> Lowest
        , ProfitMargin DESC -- Highest profitMargin
 LIMIT 1                    -- return only 1 result, i.e the first/best
```

Comment: Thanls for the ans. I am sorry if initial question is not clear ... I will edit. Actually there are two tables: Routing and Criteria. Criteria table is also having priority column which is telling us the order of application of sorting criteria and there applicability.

Comment: Ok, please include the other table and sample input and output in original question.

Comment: Hi Imre, I have updated the quest. Please let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks in advance :)